# How to compile cs files into separate dll

Tags: c#, class, class-library

I have a class library and cs files which are for different objectives. One is extension class, the other is windows form control the other is asp.net control, etc.

I want to compile all these cs files into a different dll.

PS: Some of them will need more than one class files maybe.

Comment: BTW You're being down-voted because what you're asking to do is certainly not normal or best practice. You should create a project per assembly you want to create (as most of the answers below suggest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try command line [compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1700bbwd%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). ([Working with the C# 2.0 Command Line Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

```
csc /target:library /out:Something.xyz *.cs
```

Comment: I can write this command into pre/post build textbox for every dll what I want.

Comment: -1 With this command you compile everything (*.cs) into one assembly. That's not what uzay95 asked for imho.

Comment: Read the post title - How to complie cs files into seperate dll? There are number of options of csc tool including compilation switches and options. It is not possible for me to write each and every command  syntax. Please note that the line in my post is a reference - How to use csc tool. For more info visit provided links.

Comment: It's ok. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE 
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" 
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll 
/debug+ 
/debug:full 
/filealign:512 
/optimize- 
/out:$(ProjectDir)bin\Debug\Extensions.dll 
/target:library 
/warnaserror- 
$(ProjectDir)Extensions.cs 
"$(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"`

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds too obvious, but if you want to compile them into seperate DLLs, why don't you create a project per assembly? So that's a project for the extension classes, one for the asp.net controls etc...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create different projects in your solution (assuming you work in Visual Studio).

Each project can have multiple (class, resource, form, etc.) files and will be compiled into different assemblies (dll's). For each project you can specify settings (assembly name, target framework, etc.).

Classes from different projects can "use" each other by making references from one project to the other. Also, different projects can specify the same namespaces so that you can structure the aplication to your own wishes.

See [Structuring Solutions And Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

All *.cs in a single class library project will compile into the same DLL, you can not split them into individual dlls. If you want a seperate dlls for each class then each should be in a seperate class library project.